# EF Code First - How do I code OnModelCreating with an entity that has property which is collection of itself?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework

I have an entity that has a property which is a collection of it's self.  How do I program my classes and the OnModelCreating to correctly create the database tables?

```
public class Category{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public ICollection<Category> PriorCategories { get; set; }
}
```

So, for the end result, I want my database mapping table (PriorCategories) to look like this:

Id - PK
ParentCategoryId - FK to Category table
ChildCategoryId - FK to Category table

How do I set up my classes and/or program the overridden OnModelCreating function?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything in OnModelCreating - the following model class will set up the relationship to itself perfectly:

```
public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? ParentCategoryId { get; set; }
    public virtual Category ParentCategory { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Category> Children { get; set; }
}
```